# In AE, is it okay to drop "with" in grammatical constructions with "to supply", "to furnish", "to present", "to issue", and "to endow"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage

In analogy with "to provide" and "to feed", which can be both constructed with and without "with" (at least in AE) -- [This application will provide you (with) all the information you need] and [The young mother feeds her baby (with) milk] -- is it also acceptable to do so -- as far as AE goes -- with such verbs as "supply", "furnish", "present", "issue", and "endow", just to mention the few ones that just came to mind?

You might want to consider the following sourced examples for this.

> And most important to supply them the means to do it.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/10/10/opinion/l-condoms-issue-should-children-have-sex-what-the-army-did-126391.html)>/
>
> Russia is supplying them the weapons of mass destruction. 
>   [source](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2013/09/12/kerry-syria-geneva-putin-chemical-weapons/2802881/)>/
>
> We presented them a good case.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/06/04/business/04scrushy.html?pagewanted=print&_r=0)>/
>
> I presented them a pretty attractive investment profile. [source](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/07/14/business/worldbusiness/14iht-citi.html)>/
>
> They are plenty of Copperheads, who furnish them all the information they want.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/1863/07/01/news/our-harrisburg-correspondence-report-spy-his-adventures-carlisle-vicinity-ewell.html)>/
>
> I am, consequently, unable to furnish you the information desired.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/1860/07/07/news/city-county-affairs-board-police-magistrates-communication-city-inspector-court.html)>/
>
> Many an establishment to furnish you the necessary goods.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/27/nyregion/picnic-spots-in-westchester-and-the-hudson-valley.html?_r=0)>/
>
> His acting career in 1984 which endowed him a tremendously rich experience of 29 years. [source](http://www.calinterpreters.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cfi2013-program.pdf)>/
>
> His life experiences have endowed him am incredibly work ethic. [source](http://www.abingdon-va.gov/pdf/bbnews-ond09.pdf)>/
>
> Mr. Nasiatka said he told them he could issue them an infraction.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/01/20/nyregion/looking-for-caves-but-digging-up-trouble.html)>/
>
> We calculate what the lodging would have cost and issue them a cash bonus.
>   [source](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/01/20/nyregion/looking-for-caves-but-digging-up-trouble.html)>/

Comment: Probably you need to look in [Levin 1993](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/E/bo3684144.html) to see what classes they belong to. _Entitle_ is not in the database, but the others belong to a number of alternations, including 1.1.2.1, Causative/Inchoative Alternation; 2.1, Dative Alternation; and 2.6, Fulfilling Alternation. They also belong to several sets of verb classes, including 13.4.1: "entrust" verbs, _credit entrust furnish issue leave present provide serve supply trust_. Details are in the book, [verb classes here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/levin.verbs2.txt).

Comment: If 'His life experiences have endowed him am incredibly work ethic' is a correct quote, I'd not use it to endorse acceptable grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all look alright to me without 'with', except for 'endow', which I believe has to take 'with', and 'entitle' which takes 'to'.

Hence I would write:

'His life experiences have endowed him with an incredible work ethic.'

'Which would entitle them to the right to attend public schools.'